# Divide and scrape <tr> groups separated by unique <td> using beautiful

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

So the webpage that I'm trying to scrape is something like this:

```
...
<tr><td colspan=3><BR><div class="list">Foo:</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="/images/2.gif" alt="Main"> <a href="/foo/1/"></A></td><td><a href="/browse/foo/1/">foo1</A></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="/images/2.gif" alt="Main"> <a href="/foo/2/"></A></td><td><a href="/browse/foo/2/">foo2</A></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="/images/1.gif" alt="Guest"> <a href="/foo/3/"></A></td><td><a href="/browse/foo/3/">foo3</A></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan=3><BR><div class="list">Bar:</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="/images/1.gif" alt="Guest"> <a href="/bar/1/"></A></td><td><a href="/browse/bar/1/">bar1</A></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="/images/1.gif" alt="Guest"> <a href="/bar/2/"></A></td><td><a href="/browse/bar/2/">bar2</A></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="/images/2.gif" alt="Main"> <a href="/bar/3/"></A></td><td><a href="/browse/bar/3/">bar3</A></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan=3>...
```

And I would like to scrape data as following:

```
...
Foo:
    foo1
    foo2
    foo3

Bar:
    bar1
    bar2
    bar3
...
```

Each contents are separated with `<tr>` with inscribed `<td colspan=3>` which make it difficult for me to scrape information... Though I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647348/find-next-siblings-until-a-certain-one-using-beautifulsoup) method I was unable to obtain data since all groups share common `<tr>` tag.

Would there be rational way to divide those sections using beautifulsoup? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear on how the method you link to didn't work. Could you show the code that you used and explain what happened?

Answer (score 0):

actually I had to deal with a lot of such datastructures lately - `td` with some `span` is a header and next `td`s are contents until new `td` with `span` comes

I use something like this.

```
class TrGrouper:
    def __init__(self, attr='colspan'):
        self.value = 0 
        self.attr = attr

    def __call__(self, tr):
        first_cell = tr.th if tr.th else tr.td
        self.value += int(first_cell.get(self.attr))
        return self.value


#usage:

import itertools

list_of_TRs = soup.find_all('tr')

for _, chunk in itertools.groupby(list_of_TRs, TrGrouper()):
    # do_something 
    # note that chunk is a generator

#or

grouped_rows = [list(chunk) for _, chunk in itertools.groupby(list_of_TRs, TrGrouper())]
```