# Getting multiple blocks of text between tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="left_panel">
    <h4>Header1</h4>
      block of text that I want.            
    <br />
    <br />
      another block of text that I want.
    <br />
    <br />
      still more text that I want.
    <br />
    <br />
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <h4>Header2</h4>
```

The number of blocks of text is variable, `Header1` is consistent, `Header2` is not.

I'm successfully extracting the first block of text using the following code:

```
def get_summary (soup):
raw = soup.find('div',{"class":"left_panel"})
for h4 in raw.findAllNext('h4'):
    following = h4.nextSibling
    return following
```

However I need all of the items sitting between the two `h4` tags, I was hoping that using `h4.nextSiblings` would solve this, but for some reason that returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I've been trying variations on this answer: [Find next siblings until a certain one using beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647348/find-next-siblings-until-a-certain-one-using-beautifulsoup) but the absence of a leading tag is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the first header and iterate over [`.next_siblings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings) until you hit an another header:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="left_panel">
    <h4>Header1</h4>
      block of text that I want.
    <br />
    <br />
      another block of text that I want.
    <br />
    <br />
      still more text that I want.
    <br />
    <br />
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <h4>Header2</h4>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
header1 = soup.find('h4', text='Header1')
for item in header1.next_siblings:
    if getattr(item, 'name') == 'h4' and item.text == 'Header2':
        break

    print item
```

---

Update (collecting texts between two `h4` tags):

```
texts = []
for item in header1.next_siblings:
    if getattr(item, 'name') == 'h4' and item.text == 'Header2':
        break

    try:
        texts.append(item.text)
    except AttributeError:
        texts.append(item)

print ''.join(texts)
```

Comment: Thanks Alecxe, this worked very well. What's the best way to combine these strings into a sane item? I'm currently adding them to a list using append, that seems a bit stupid.

Comment: @woodbine please see the update. Basically, it the same as you've said about - maintaining a list of texts. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why are you passing `soup` as an argument but you don't use it.

If you use the correct soup instance you shouldn't get that error. `findAllNext(h4)` returns `<h4>Header1</h4>` and `<h4>Header2</h4>`, applying `nextSibling` on each returns the text sibling, which are

```
block of text that I want.
```

and

```
')
```

in your case.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was calling tender_soup in the original code but used 'soup' to simplify it. I forgot to remove the 'tender_' from the subsequent call. Have adjusted.